# Specify default pull branch for a given remote

Tags: git

When I `git pull`, I pull from the default branch on my default remote.
If I would like to pull from the remote "upstream", I have to specify the upstream branch that I would like to pull from:

`git pull upstream name_of_branch`.

I would like to specify a default branch for a given remote, so that I can achieve the above just by

`git pull upstream`

The reason is one of laziness - `name_of_branch` is in this case a bit of an long awkward name, and I have to do this relatively often.

I have not found a way to do this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If the duplicate link does not resolve your problem, drop a comment and the question can be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to setup tracking to your remote branch like this

`git branch -u upstream/name_of_branch`

and then you can just `git pull`