# How can I specify default branch for pulling from remote - while I have one remote configured already as a default?

Tags: git, configuration

I have setup of my personal fork with:

`master` branch mirroring `master` branch in upstream repo and `fork` that is my main branch including my changes - and other feature/WIP/testing/testcase branches as usual.

`master` branch has a default configured remote `origin/master` where my repo lives and where I push update `master`.

But I am pulling from `upstream` remote.

How can I configure git so I can:

- `git push` while on `master` branch and push to `origin`
- `git pull upstream` while on `master` branch and pull from `upstream/master`  (right now I need to do `git pull upstream master`)

Now `git pull upstream` is resulting in

> Because this is not the default configured remote for your current branch

[specify default branch for a non-default remote for pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456709/specify-default-branch-for-a-non-default-remote-for-pull) may seem to be a duplicate but is not - "This does not answer the question, since this only works for the default remote (origin)!"

The same [Specify default pull branch for a given remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928843/specify-default-pull-branch-for-a-given-remote) - it allows setting only one

Comment: recently it got extra annoying as even `git pull upstream master` is not always working (as some repos decided that renaming `master` to `main` is a good use of everyone time and effective way to reduce amount of evil in the world). And `git pull upstream` `git pull upstream master` `git pull upstream main` is getting ridiculous.

Comment: If I understood correctly, `git pull upstream master` works as intended?

Comment: @ValBerthe Yes.

Comment: Have you tried setting `default = current` in `[push]` and `[pull]` sections of your `.gitconfig` file ?

Comment: @ValBerthe I just tried, it had no effect at all. I restarted command line window to ensure that new file version was loaded.

Comment: Won't help your use case, but I recommend *avoiding* the `git pull` command entirely. Run your own two-separate-commands. You then control the second command explicitly. Of course you're trying to avoid being explicit in the first place. But this *does* give you a *new option*, which I'll write up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a remote so that it has different push and pull urls, e.g : `git fetch origin` would fetch from `upstream`, `git push origin` would push to `fork`,
however I don't know of a stock configuration option to specify two distinct branch names depending on the remote.

IMHO the easiest way would be to have the branches in your `fork` repo follow the same names as the `upstream` repo, so that you can push/pull to branch `main` in both cases.

One other generic option is : you can define aliases to run the appropriate commands.

---

Here is how to set up `origin` with two distinct urls :

```
# you can have distinct protocols for both urls :
git remote set-url origin https://upstream.repo
git remote set-url --push origin ssh://fork.repo
```

With your `origin` remote set up like this, if you set the upstream branch for your local `master` branch to `origin/main` :

```
git branch -u origin/main master
```

the default action for :

- `git push` will be to push your local branch to `main` on `fork`
- `git pull` will be to fetch anbd merge branch `main` from `upstream`

Comment: > IMHO the easiest way would be to have the branches in your fork repo follow the same names as the upstream repo

they do this (`master` is used for the main upstream branch - both in `upstream` and `origin` remotes)

> so that you can push/pull to refs/heads/main in both cases.

I am confused by that. So I would do `git pull refs/heads/main`?

Comment: No : set your branch remote to `origin/main` : `git branch -u origin/main`, now `git push` pushes to branch `main` on  `fork`, and `git pull` fetches from branch `main` on `upstream`

Comment: `refs/heads/main` is what gets written in your config file

Comment: edited the answer, to hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to ditch `git pull` entirely, here's how to automate the job.

Step 1: write yourself a new Git command.  Let's call it `up` for now.  This command is a simple script, which we'll see at the bottom of this posting.  To make it an executable Git command, make it an executable script named `git-up` and put this somewhere such that your `$PATH` will find it.  Running `git up` will now run your `git-up` script.

Step 2: in each repository in which you want this to happen, run:

```
git config branch.<name>.up origin/<other-name>
```

where `<name>` is the name of the branch you want your script to update, and `origin/<other-name>` is the remote-tracking name in your Git repository that will be updated by `git fetch`.

Step 3: replace `git pull` with `git up`.

Now for the script.  We'll need it to be executable (remember to `chmod +x`!), and run by a shell such as /bin/sh or /bin/bash, so:

```
#! /bin/sh
```

The script should:

- figure out which branch we are on right now
- locate the `branch.name.up` setting: error if not set
- run `git fetch`
- run `git merge $setting`

These steps are accomplished with:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) || exit
up=$(git config --get branch.$branch.up) || {
    echo "no name configured for git-up for $branch" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
git fetch && git merge $up
```

This is all untested, so test each part and make any necessary fixes.